# Template Matching Java without opencv or 3rd party

Tags: java, matlab, template-matching

I am trying to do template matching in java:

This is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;

public class pro {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            // RGB pixel values
            byte[] pixels;
 
            File inp=new File("TenCardG.jpg");
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inp);
            int width = image.getWidth();
            int height = image.getHeight();
            
           // System.out.println("Type: "+image.getColorModel());
            
            
            pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
            System.out.println("Dimension of image" + width + " "+height+" "+ " pixels length "+ pixels.length);
        
        
       
            //rgb2gray in a 2D array grayImage                 
            int pr;// red
            int pg;//  green
            int pb;// blue     
  
           short [][] grayImage =new short [height][width];
           int cord;
           for (int i=0; i<height;i++)
               for(int j=0;j<width;j++)
               {                     
                   cord= 3*(i*width+j);
                   pr= ((short) pixels[cord] & 0xff); // red
                   pg= (((short) pixels[cord+1] & 0xff));//  green
                   pb= (((short) pixels[cord+2] & 0xff));// blue                
                   
                   grayImage[i][j]=(short)Math.round(0.299 *pr + 0.587 * pg  + 0.114 * pb); 
           
                   
               }   
       
               
           
          
            Image scaledImage = image.getScaledInstance(-1,-1, 0);
            ImageIO.write(
                    add_Rectangle(scaledImage),
                    "jpg",
                    new File("TenCardG2.jpg"));

     
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done, check the generated TenCardG2 image at its left top corner");

    }

    // Add a rectangle of side size 50, 70 at coordinate 0.0 in image img
    public static BufferedImage add_Rectangle(Image img) {

        if (img instanceof BufferedImage) {
            return (BufferedImage) img;
        }

        // Create a buffered image with transparency
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  
        Graphics2D g2D = bi.createGraphics();
        g2D.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g2D.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2D.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 70);              
        g2D.dispose();
        return bi;
    } 

}
```

**This is the source image:[10 of hearts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhZIw.jpg)**
**This is the template image: [Picture of heart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84a0a.jpg)**

**[This a matlab code i guess which we change it to java and then implement into that code. I guess that matlab code this it compares bit by bit like and image can be compressed. if so, it will not match. its static processing. we need dynamic one. I don't know where to implement that one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdoMV.png)**

**[When i run my code which i provide up i get this output which i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crB20.png)**

**[But i should this final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OklVF.png)**

Can please try to help me

Comment: *ImageIO.write(add_Rectangle(scaledImage), "jpg", new File("TenCardG2.jpg"));* is being called `height` times with the same coordinates, so you're going to get the same rectangle drawn

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Either **a.** Move coordinates or **b.** Use an `AffineTransform` to do that. Former is prob. simpler